# tracking multiple redirects in browser plug-in

Tags: asp.net, browser, redirect, twebbrowser

If there are multiple redirects happening within ASP.NET, is there a tool for any browser to track all redirects?  Let's suppose clicking on one page redirects you to page2.aspx, and then page2.aspx redirects you to page3.aspx.  I'd like to capture both redirects somewhere.  Is this possible in any browser plug-ins without debugging the source code?

Comment: You will just run fiddler then open your page, then you will find all requests in the main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any http capture tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/). It works with IE, Chrome etc. (in Firefox you must disable add-on version compatibility check, otherwise it will not work).

Comment: Are there any gotcha's using Fiddler?  Or any good setup recommendations so I don't spend hours with fiddling before I Fiddle?  I'll mark your comment with an up-vote for anyone who can help.  :-)  I'll mark this as the answer since you posted first.. but only after I get things working.

Comment: Yes, there are some 'gotchas' (Fiddler is not the one to be blamed though...). When debugging WebServices, or an ordinary HTTP communication in ASP.NET, you must set Fiddler proxy in web config, see http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Mar/14/Debugging-Http-or-Web-Services-Calls-from-ASPNET-with-Fiddler. I'm using Fiddler more than 3 years and can't say anything bad about it, great tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the magic tool named "[fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)", it will let you know all the requests that happens from your website